# How to compare objects from a same class based on their attributes?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I have this objects:

```
COSTOS Costos = new COSTOS(1781, 359.13, "BISAG.SUP.PUER.TRA.I", "67550T9AT00ZZ");
        COSTOS Herramienta = new COSTOS(1795, 299.11, "BISAG.INF.PUER.TRA.I", "67960T2MT02ZZ");
```

And this is my class:

```
public class COSTOS implements Comparable<COSTOS>{

    public int referencia;
    public double monto;
    public String descripcion;
    public String NumeroParte;

    //Constructor


    //getters setters
```

Also, i implemented HashCode and equals:

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((NumeroParte == null) ? 0 : NumeroParte.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((descripcion == null) ? 0 : descripcion.hashCode());
        long temp;
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(monto);
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + referencia;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        COSTOS other = (COSTOS) obj;
        if (NumeroParte == null) {
            if (other.NumeroParte != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!NumeroParte.equals(other.NumeroParte))
            return false;
        if (descripcion == null) {
            if (other.descripcion != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!descripcion.equals(other.descripcion))
            return false;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(monto) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.monto))
            return false;
        if (referencia != other.referencia)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

> How could i implement a method that could print all the attributes
>   that are not equals?

I tried to use "import java.util.Objects;" to use: "Objects.hash(referencia, monto, descripcion, NumeroParte);", so that may give me the results to print

Comment: Can you please clarify precisely where you are having difficulty?  This should either include a code sample that doesn't work as you'd expect (with an explanation as to why), or a specific point at which you're unable to produce said code.

Comment: Alright... i'm just trying to compare those objects using HashCode and equals, but i need to print the attributes that are not equals... that's all the code i have, i was wondering if someone could help me trying to print those elements

Comment: So you want to print out the attributes which are not the same *only for 2 objects*?

Comment: yes, how could i start?

Comment: *"How could i implement a method that could print all the attributes that are not equals?"* You write a method very similar to the `equals` method, except you print something instead of returning `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your methods can be simplified by using the null-safe [`Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) helper methods added in Java 7:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + Objects.hashCode(this.NumeroParte);
    result = prime * result + Objects.hashCode(this.descripcion);
    result = prime * result + Double.hashCode(this.monto);
    result = prime * result + this.referencia;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    COSTOS other = (COSTOS) obj;
    return (Objects.equals(this.NumeroParte, other.NumeroParte)
         && Objects.equals(this.descripcion, other.descripcion)
         && Double.doubleToLongBits(this.monto) == Double.doubleToLongBits(other.monto)
         && this.referencia == other.referencia);
}
```

> How could i implement a method that could print all the attributes that are not equals?

To print differences, do the same comparisons as the `equals` method:

```
public void printDifferences(COSTOS other) {
    if (! Objects.equals(this.NumeroParte, other.NumeroParte))
        System.out.println("Different NumeroParte: " + this.NumeroParte + " != " + other.NumeroParte);
    if (! Objects.equals(this.descripcion, other.descripcion))
        System.out.println("Different descripcion: " + this.descripcion + " != " + other.descripcion);
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.monto) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.monto))
        System.out.println("Different monto: " + this.monto + " != " + other.monto);
    if (this.referencia != other.referencia)
        System.out.println("Different referencia: " + this.referencia + " != " + other.referencia);
}
```

Comment: Nice, but how i could print from that method?

System.out.println(printDifferences(COSTOS other));  ??

Comment: @AntonioAlejos Ehh what? Did you *look* at the code? The method is called `printDifferences` (notice the **print** part of the name), and it does the `System.out.println`.

Comment: Yes i know, but i implemented that method in my class and when i run my project it doesn't print anything because i need to call that method in my main class...

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to call a method in Java? Perhaps you should (re)read your Java Guide on how methods work in Java. To help, try: `c1.printDifferences(c2)` where `c1` and `c2` are instances of class `COSTOS`

Comment: Alright, that worked for me, thank you so much!!
I'm learning this, this is kinda new for me.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you requirement correctly, you want to print out the values of attributes which are not the same in 2 objects, then you can create a method as follows.

```
public void compareAttributes(COSTOS other) {
    if (this.getMonto() != other.getMonto()) {
       System.out.println("Not equal. This obj : " + this.getMonto() 
                        + " Other obj : " + other.getMonto());
    }

    // you can do the same for the remaining attributes.
}
```

EDIT:

As @Andreas, pointed out in the comments you should place this method in your `COSTOS` class itself so every object can be compared easily.

Comment: Either make the method `static`, or remove parameter `obj1` and use `this` instead (in which case `obj2` should be renamed to `other` for consistency).

Comment: Yes, is should be added to `COSTOS` class as a non-static 1-arg method, similar to `equals` and `compareTo`. If not, the 2-arg method is required. The 2-arg method should be `static`, whether added to `COSTOS` class or some other class.